# Bounding the integral of a function by the integral of its derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, sobolev-spaces

I have no idea where to begin for this question, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $\Omega$ be a square with side 1. Show that 
$$\left(\int_{\Omega} v^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \leq \left( \int_{\Omega} |\nabla v|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}$$
for all $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

The 1D analogue of this problem is really straightforward with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I don't think that can be used for this problem again, so I'm a stuck.

Comment: It is the so called "Poincaré inequality".

Comment: I thought the LHS of the Poincare inequality was $||u-\bar u||_{L^p}$, where $\bar u$ is the average of $u$ over the domain.

Comment: I expand my comment into an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus is still the essential step.  You only need to use it once ("in one direction").  Show the inequality with the gradient replaced by just one of the partial derivatives, which itself is obviously less than the L2 norm of the gradient.  (Based on my rusty memory of the proof from Kesavan's book)

Comment: This is a variant of the Poincare inequality for the case when the function vanishes on the boundary. They call it Dirichlet-Poincare inequality here http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-152-introduction-to-partial-differential-equations-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lecture4.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poincaré inequality holds for every subspace of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ which has compact embedding in $L^p$ and does not contain constants.

Let me be more precise.

> **Theorem.** Let $\Omega$ be an open, Lipschitz, bounded, connected set in $\mathbb R^d$ and let $p \in [1,+\infty)$. Let $W \subset W^{1,p}$ be a subspace which has compact embedding in $L^p(\Omega)$ and does not contain constants. Then there exists a constant $C=C(\Omega,p)>0$ such that
>   $$
> \Vert u \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)} \le C \Vert \nabla u \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)} \qquad \forall u \in W.
> $$

*Proof.* By contradiction, suppose for every $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists a function $u_n \in W$ such that
$$
\Vert u_n \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)} > n \Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)}.
$$
Clearly, it is not restrictive to assume $\Vert u_n \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)} = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$, hence we have
$$
\Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)}< \frac{1}{n}.
$$
In other words, the sequence $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is bounded in $W$; since by assumption the injection $W \hookrightarrow L^p$ is compact, we deduce that - up to subsequences - $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$. Furthermore, we also have $\nabla u_n \to 0$ and it is easy to see that $u \in W$, in particular $\nabla u = 0$. Thus $u$ is a constant function in $W$, which is a contradiction. QED

In particular, there are two nice subspaces satisfying hypothesis: $W_0^{1,p}$ (which gives what you are looking for in the case $p=2$) and 
$$
W_{\star}^{1,p} := \left\{u \in W^{1,p}: \, \int u = 0 \right\},
$$
i.e. the space of functions with zero average (this choice of $W$ gives the inequality you were speaking about in the comment).

**Further comments.**

1. I think there exist tons of proofs of Poincaré inequality; I suggest you to give a look to some classical book about Sobolev spaces, for instance Brezis' one (see Chap. 9, Cor. 9.19) or Adams.
2. The best constant $C$ is related to the geometry of $\Omega$ (and also to the eigenvalues of the laplacian operator).

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful!